# Can I change my location on the device to test a user's location?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

I'm using the following code to get the current lat loc of the user. I would like to change the currentLocation of the user on the device to see how the map is populated with annotations. I would like to emulate the problem a tester of the app is having on the device in another country than I'm in. For him the map doesn't load the annotation whereas for me it works fine in the Simulator and the device (we're using the same device model etc.). I did try setting the `currentUserLatitude currentUserLongitude` to my tester's values but the map added the annotations fine for me.

```
-(void)loadMap{
 CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [self getLocation];
    currentUserLatitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", coordinate.latitude];
    currentUserLongitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", coordinate.longitude];

    NSLog(@"*dLatitude : %@", currentUserLatitude);
    NSLog(@"*dLongitude : %@",currentUserLongitude);
}

-(CLLocationCoordinate2D) getLocation{
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    CLLocation *location = [locationManager location];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [location coordinate];

    return coordinate;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't simulate a location on a physical device.

However, it is possible to test your app in the simulator and [have it claim to be in whatever location you would like](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/GettingStartedwithiOSStimulator/GettingStartedwithiOSStimulator.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012848-CH5-SW13).

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can change your device location. Run your project and go to Xcode Debug Area Click on Simulate Location and select the location from list.Before that you need to allow simulate location from edit scheme 
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set coordinates manually

```
-(CLLocationCoordinate2D) getLocation{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(47.1726, 9.5153);
    return coordinate;
}
```

Or use simulator.